# Time complexity of summing ranges

Tags: python, time-complexity, big-o

I have the following function which computes the sum of all numbers from `a` to `b`. I'd like to know how to find its time complexity (without using the master theorem). I'd love getting an intuitive explanation and how to approach such problem.

```
def sum_func(a, b):
    if a == b:
        return a

    mid = (a+b) // 2
    return sum_func(a, mid) + sum_func(mid+1, b)
```

Comment: This Question is independent from the concrete coding, so SO is not the place to ask such a Question

Comment: @YannickFunk It is a question specific to programming, and non-programmers would not be interested in the question, so it is clearly within the scope of Stack Overflow. I invite you to read other questions tagged `time-complexity` here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say `n` is the size of the range, i.e. the amount of numbers to be added together. Imagine those numbers as the leaves of a [binary tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree), where each node in the tree represents a subrange, and when the function is called to sum that node's subrange, it makes two recursive calls represented by that node's two children in the binary tree.

A binary tree with `n` leaves has `2*n - 1` nodes, each representing a recursive call, so the recursive function is called `O(n)` times. Each time the function is called, it does `O(1)` work plus the recursive calls; therefore the total work done is `O(n)`.